# Apple Instruments can't locate a dSYM for any of the selected libraries when trying to not show assembly

Tags: c++, xcode, instruments, debug-symbols

I'm trying to use Apple Instruments (on El Capitan) without having to create a project in XCode. I created a time profiler, set up my project, and then started profiling the project. I can see all of my function names, and relevant times are displayed correctly. However, when I double click on a function name, only the assembly information is displayed.

The first thing I tried to do to fix this was go to `File -> Symbols` and then select the `Incomplete` symbols option. When in this mode, I can see my dSYM that it cannot find which contains my source code information. So, I click on `Locate` and navigate to the dSYM it seemingly cannot find. After selecting it, I get this error:

```
No new libraries to symbolicate
The specified path didn't locate a dSYM for any of the selected libraries.
```

This is incorrect, and I can even go into the dSYM package itself, and compare it to other dSYM packages it finds correctly in the same path. Comparing the `info.plist` file that the dSYM generates, everything looks the same, so I don't know why it can't find it.

Since I really only wanted to see one file's source code, I double clicked on the function. I get a little warning exclamation point that allows me to manually locate the source code file. Great! I click this button, directly point it to the `.cpp` file that it "cannot" find, and click ok. Despite doing this, nothing ends up happening and the source code still says it is unavailable. When I click on the `Unavailable` portion, it states this: `The file doesn’t exist.`

Finally, I tried to see the source code by right clicking on the function I wanted to look at, and clicking `Locate dSYM`. After selecting the correct dSYM, I get this error:

```
The UUID of '/Users/me/project/trunk/lib/libCore.0.dylib.dSYM' 
does not match the UUID for 'libCore.0.dylib'
```

I checked the UUID of both the dSYM and dylib with:

```
dwarfdump --uuid "libCore.0.dylib.dSYM" | cut -d' ' -f2
dwarfdump --uuid "libCore.0.dylib" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

And they do not match up.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem? Is there a way to fix the UUID problem? Everything in Apple Instruments works fine otherwise, and it can somehow locate a dSYMs in the same directory as the dSYM that it supposedly can not find. I've had this issue for a while and am about to just give up on Instruments :(

Comment: Are you sure the .dSYM was rebuilt more recently than the library? What happens if you just delete it and re-run `dsymutil` on the library (assuming it hasn't been stripped)?

Comment: Any luck here???

Comment: @orkenstein I don't know if this will be relevant, as the project I was working on at the time used make files for everything. But what worked for me was the following: delete the dSYM and dylib file, run `make clean && make && make install` and then check the UUID using the command I mentioned in the original post. What was strange is it took a few tries of this to work if I remember correctly.